# Django 2.1+ bulk update records with the count of their related records?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to bulk update all of my records in table A with the count of their related records in table B.

I'd like to do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Count


table_b_subquery = TableB.objects.filter(a_id=OuterRef('id'))

TableA.objects.all().update(table_b_count=Count(Subquery(table_b_subquery)))
```

That would be the equivalent of this NON-BULK method:

```
# Non-Bulk

for record in TableA.objects.all():
  record.table_b_count = record.table_b_set.count()
```

The error I get trying the bulk method is:

```
*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Aggregate functions are not allowed in this query
```

How do I do a seemingly simply count of related records in a bulk update? Ideally I'd like to apply a simple field filter to the count of table B as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a subquery for the count (rather than just the countable objects), which is a bit of a hassle as regular aggregate queries like `count()` or `aggregate()` tend to execute immediately, whereas subqueries need to be lazy. That's why the `annotate()` workaround below is needed:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Count

table_b_subquery = Subquery(TableB.objects
    .filter(a_id=OuterRef('id'))
    .values('a_id')
    .annotate(cnt=Count('a_id'))
    .values('cnt')
)

TableA.objects.update(table_b_count=table_b_subquery)
```

Comment: I found this to be better than django 2.2's `bulk_update method` - my implentation of `bulk_update` was rather slow since I was calling the `table_b_set` on each loop. This was much more efficient. I'm also a little suspect of the way `bulk_update` wants me to fill up a list with 1 million rows.  Thanks Endre

Comment: it's more efficiency than `bulk_update`! very nice performance!

Answer (score 3):

Endre's answer is what I'm looking for! I just found a new feature in Django 2.2 that might be worth using though and I'm conflicted. I'm not sure which is better.

Django 2.2 has `bulk_update`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_update

So with `bulk_update` for my question, I'd do:

```
records = []
for record in TableA.objects.all():
  counted_record = record.table_b_count = record.table_b_set.count()
  records.append(counted_record)

TableA.objects.bulk_update(records, ['table_b_count'], batch_size=100000) 

# This is acting on Table A with 1,000,000 rows and Table B with 5,000,000 rows.
```

Anyone have thoughts on whether Endre's answer or the new Django 2.2 method is better in this case, with millions of rows?

Comment: `bulk_update` is intended for a different use case (where you update individual objects with data coming from outside the database). If you can keep the entire operation within the database, as in your case, there is no reason to first retrieve all calculated values and then send them back to the database.

Comment: big +1, the difference is 20min vs 4 hours.

Comment: Imho 20min still sounds very high for 1M linked to 5M records. Maybe try a sub query with count + group by on a_id and feed the result into update. Should finish much faster.